# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" when adding lists to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm creating a function that consolidates a couple of lists into a string and am encountering the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TraditionalRoute\BioKeywords.py", line 65, in <module>
    print(PrintKeyDefs())
  File "TraditionalRoute\BioKeywords.py", line 30, in PrintKeyDefs
    defsTwo = dict(map(None, letters, defsOne))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

My code is as follows:

```
# print keyword and three definitions, one of which is the correct definition
def PrintKeyDefs():
   print('\nRandomly selected keyword:',SelectKeyword(),'\n')
   # definitions below
   defsOne = []
   defsOne.append(keywords[ChosenKeyword]) # choosing the keyword
   RandDefCount = 0
   while RandDefCount < 2: # adding two random keywords to the list
      defsOne.append(keywords[random.choice(words)])
      RandDefCount += 1
   random.shuffle(defsOne) # randomizing the keywords
   letters = ['A) ','B) ','C) ']
   defsTwo = dict(map(None, letters, defsOne)) # trying to put them together in a dict. the problem is here
   defsThree = ''
   defsThree += '\n'.join(defsTwo) # changing to a string
   return defsThree
```

Would anyone be able to suggest a possible fix as I've spent quite a while on this and haven't figured it out yet. Thanks.

EDIT: Forgot to mention I'm using Python 3

Comment: Why did you vandalize your own question? That's not acceptable. I've removed the hostname though in case that was the reason for it. If you need it removed from the revision history, too, for whatever reason please flag your question and ask for the old revisions to be destroyed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Python 2, then either `map` or `dict` is bound to `None`. Check the *rest* of your code for assignments to either name.

Note that instead of `map(None, iterable1, iterable2)` you can use `zip(iterable1, iterable2)` to get the same output.

If you are using Python 3, then the `map()` method does **not** support `None` as a first argument:

```
>>> list(map(None, [1], [2]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

and you certainly want to use `zip()` there:

```
defsTwo = dict(zip(letters, defsOne))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Python 3 then first argument to [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#map) is ought to be a function. You're passing `None` so it tries to call a `None`. This is a different than in Python 2, when `None` was treated like an identity function ([Python's 2 map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)).

For Python 2 case see [Martijn Pieters's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19954471/2642204).

Answer (score -1):

**#Use Of Zip() function**

**#Generate tuple**

x=zip( range(5), range(1,20,2) )
print("Tuple : ",tuple(x))

**#Generate List**

x=zip( range(5), range(1,20,2) )
print("List  : ",list(x))

**#Generate dictonary**

x=zip( range(5), range(1,20,2) )
print("Dictonary  : ",dict(x))